# How do I determine the total number of cities that have less than seven characters?

Tags: r

I am using the data frame `swiss` and I would like to determine the total number of cities that have less than seven characters. Can it be done with `sum` and `nchar` ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

As @KFB noted, I should clarify the other issue and give another example. I might have not the best example, but this can show what I meant in the comments.

```
housing
```

So in this data I have the column `type` and I would like to count how many values
have less that 7 characters with the `sum` and `nchar` command. The same can be done with
the `Infl` column.

Comment: I updated the post.  I am guessing `housing` data is from `library(MASS)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
  sum(nchar(rownames(swiss))<7)
  #[1] 16
```

Counting a specific column in data.frame (assuming it is `nchar`)

```
  nchar(swiss$Fertility)
  #[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4
  #[39] 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4
```

If you want to find the length of each column, it is just `nrow(swiss)` as this is not going to change for any specific column.

#### Update

```
 library(MASS)
 data(housing)
 sapply(housing[,c("Infl", "Type")], function(x) sum(nchar(as.character(x))<7)) 
 #Infl Type 
 # 72   36
```

For just one column, you don't need `sapply`

```
 sum(nchar(as.character(housing[,"Infl"])) <7)
 #[1] 72
```

Comment: What if I have to count a specific column in the data frame?

Comment: length(your_data$data_column)

Comment: @Trik23 Not sure I understand your question.  Do you want to do `nchar` on a specific column?

Comment: @Trik23, Since there are no character data in swiss data, better format it into another question with proper sample data.

Comment: @akrun Edited my post for clarification!